# Using a folder for personal modules in Python

Tags: python, module, python-module

I have created a folder named `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\perso` and inside I have put a file `mymodule.py`. The goal is to have this module accessible from any future Python script.

Let's do a `D:\My Documents\test.py` file:

```
import mymodule   #fails
import perso.mymodule   #fails
```

**Why does it fail? How to import a module from `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\perso`? What are the best practice for using user-modules in all Python scripts of the same computer?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. check PythonPath
2. create `__init__.py` to use perso as package

Comment: Indeed, `__init__.py` was the solution!

Answer (score 2):

**Python Modules:**

In order to create a module you can do the following:

1. under `<Python_DIR>\Lib\site-packages`:
   put you directory `<module>`. This directory contains your classes.
2. In `<Python_DIR>\Lib\site-packages\<module>` put an init file `__init__.py`,
   This file define what's in the directory, and may apply some logic if needed.
   for example: 
      `__all__ = ["class_1", "class_2",]`.

Than, to import:

```
from <your_module> import <your_class>
```

For more information, read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).